# vba rango de dos hojas diferentes

Tags: excel, vba

Hola esta macro deberia decir que celdas de las dos hojas estan vacias de un rango determinado pero no lo hace alguna ayuda?

```
   Option Explicit
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim C As Range
    Dim MsgStr As String

    For Each C In Range("Sheet1!D8:D13,Sheet2!C7:C3") '
        If C.Value2 = "" Then
            If MsgStr = "" Then
                MsgStr = C.Address(False, False)
            Else
                MsgStr = MsgStr & "," & C.Address(False, False)
            End If
        End If
    Next C

    MsgBox MsgStr & "cells are empty"

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Para comprobar si una celda está vacía deberías utilizar otra estrategia, por ejemplo con la función `IsEmpty()` que se aplica al rango, o a la celda (y no a su `value`). Por lo que la comprobación de si está vacía sería `If IsEmpty(C) Then`:

```
If IsEmpty(C) Then
   If MsgStr = "" Then
       MsgStr = C.Address(False, False)
   Else
       MsgStr = MsgStr & "," & C.Address(False, False)
End If
```

El bucle principal `for each` que tienes, no funcionará tal como está puesto que estás intentando seleccionar un rango que empieza en una hoja y termina en otra. Deberás hacer dos bucles, uno por cada hoja, o bien hacer uno genérico que recorra las hojas del archivo.

```
   Dim C As Range
   Dim MsgStrSheet1 As String
   Dim MsgStrSheet2 As String

For Each C In Range("Sheet1!D8:D13") '
    If IsEmpty(C) Then Then
        If MsgStrSheet1= "" Then
            MsgStrSheet1 = C.Address(False, False)
        Else
            MsgStrSheet1 = MsgStrSheet1 & "," & C.Address(False, False)
        End If
    End If
Next C

For Each C In Range("Sheet2!C7:C3") '
    If IsEmpty(C) Then
        If MsgStrSheet2 = "" Then
            MsgStrSheet2 = C.Address(False, False)
        Else
            MsgStrSheet2 = MsgStrSheet2 & "," & C.Address(False, False)
        End If
    End If
Next C

MsgBox MsgStrSheet1 & " cells are empty in Sheet1"
MsgBox MsgStrSheet2 & " cells are empty in Sheet2"
```

Comment: y para que funcione con rangos diferentes de celdas diferentes como se hace?

Comment: No es posible, Deberás hacer dos bucles `for each`, uno para cada worksheet.

Comment: la idea de la macro es que me diga en una ventana de mensajes que celdas estan vacias de cada hoja, con lo que me has dicho funcionaria?

Comment: Claro que si, he editado la respuesta con los dos `for each`

Comment: no detecta la sheet2 solo tiene en cuenta las celdas de la sheet1

Comment: que no, no funciona